# Can EEPROMs have feedback networks to make state machines?

Tags: digital-logic, feedback, non-volatile-memory

I have imagined a simple system that detects in which direction a stepper is going based on the voltages across the windings, and which emulates from that two end switches relying only on one single switch activated at either end. This solution is solely based on a single 64kB 8-bit EEPROM (11 bits adresses used out of 13), but it requires something fundamental:

Is it possible to tie the output of an EEPROM to its inputs in the following way, to effectively use the EEPROM as some sort of Flip Flop with unit delay for a state machine? In this example, B has dummy values but it really is the useful output of the EEPROM.
[image]

I have done the following exercise which seems to validate this: assuming A mem is initially 0, and A now is 1, A mem becomes 1 and stays at 1. This seems to work for all states.

Comment: Put a register in the feedback path and yes. Common in the early 80s when TTL PROMs were cheaper than PALs (before FPGAs came along)

Comment: @BrianDrummond: By register do you mean to latch the output? Could you provide an example?

Comment: A famous example of doing exactly this: Steve Wozniak's design for the Apple II floppy disk controller.  Its heart is a 256 x 8 bit PROM, with a 4-bit latch clocked at 2 MHz to maintain the state.

Comment: @jasonharper: That's precisely what I thought of when I read the question.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen someone's hobby "CPU" made this way somewhere.

Comment: @user253751: I've been toying with the idea of seeing if I could fit an imitation of Milton Bradley's "Simon®" brand electronic game in a shifter-plus-ROM state machine without making the ROM much bigger than the one the actual toy's microcontroller, and without using too much discrete logic besides.  Mainly a CD4517 64x2 storage shift register, a 74LS595 for 8 outputs, a 74LS161 for 8 inputs, a couple of state registers, and some timing-control logic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put a register in the feedback path and yes.

Common in the early 80s when TTL PROMs were cheaper than PALs (before FPGAs came along)

Use a clocked register rather than a latch, to hold the ROM output. This register holds the state which forms part of the next ROM address (and may hold outputs too). Then inputs form a further part of the ROM address, so the next state depends on the current state and the inputs. State changes can only happen on clock edges.

As seen in [this article](http://electronics-diy.com/electronic_schematic.php?id=702) mentioned in a comment.

Comment: Brings back some old memories. Pretty sure I read more than one article on the subject back in the 80's. Ah! Look at that: https://www.google.com/search?q=How+use+EPROM+for+state+machine+logic%3F

Answer (score 3):

Not really a flip-flop but a state-table lookup.

But the answer is yes, you can do this but there are other options that may be better.

There are PALs (Programmable Array Logic) and CPLDs that might suite your application better.

But if you are just doing this as an experiment or proof-of-concept, go ahead.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't see this working reliably.

When the address inputs of an EEPROM change to access a new location, there will be a period of time when the outputs are changing unpredictably from the contents of the old location to the new one. Some outputs will probably change quicker than others. If some of these changing outputs are being fed straight back to the address inputs the period of unpredictability will be extended further, and this may continue indefinitely or it might settle down to some value that could be - well, unpredictable.

State machines normally use flip flops or latches to store the current state and a combination of gates to determine the new state based on the current state and the inputs in order to provide predictable and reliable progress through the state table based on a periodic clock signal.

Comment: I agree but it seems like it would work if you register the feedback to a clock.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this is insightful. Could you provide an example of such simple state machines built with flip flops but without a clock? In my application 4 signals are monitored and no single clock is available.

Comment: I don't think it can work without a clock of some sort.

Comment: It needs a clock signal. It's possible to design state machines without, but not using EEPROMs the way you want to. A clock signal is easy to generate, doesn't need to be anything fancy.

Comment: It can be made to work without a clock, I don't recall the details, but I have seen asynchronous logic constructed that way in the past. A EE I worked with long ago, needed to control power on/off to multiple digital and analog circuits, and he did it with EPROM. He basically needed to wait for several power supplies to stabilize for a minimum period of time, and then sequence power-on the analog and digital circuits, such that they would not destroy each other.

Comment: @jwdonahue it can work without a clock if there is not feedback. Using an EEPROM as an arbitrary logic device is an established idea. But without a clock, I am skeptical that a useful FEEDBACK system can work, because of logic hazards and because the rate of change of signals would not be controlled by anything other than propagation delay.

Comment: Yup, there were some R/C circuits in there for sure, but it worked. Pretty sure that same EE tore it all out a few years later for an off the shelf watch-dog circuit and a GAL. I remember that it worked in some pretty nasty environments (the cabs of overhead electric gantry cranes) and could never have been battery powered ;). I also remember having to throw a lot of dead-bugs and extra caps into the prototype the first time we installed it on a crane for testing (spurious resets), but that turned out to be a problem with the Proxim modems we were using.